# Отрицательное изменение репутации на вкладке в профиле после разбана

Tags: дефект

Наблюдаю в профиле сию любопытную картину:

[image]

После разбана там скорее должно быть не уменьшение, а увеличение репутации на 19 240.

Comment: Не хватает free hand circle на картинке

Comment: @alexolut Исправлено.

Comment: Кто-то не считает это багом? Кстати, разумнее, кмк, разместить это на MSE.

Comment: @alexolut Кто-то не любит меня скорее. :D

Comment: @Squidward Добавите ссылку на вопрос MSE? Мы вас поддержим.